# Windows's top border overlaps menu bar

Tags: arch-linux, desktop-environment, desktop, mate-desktop

**Environment**

- OS: Arch Linux
- Desktop Environment: Mate
- Display: Dual displays of the same resolutions and the same inches. Uncommonly, they are aligned vertically (see picture below).
- Location of Menubar: On each display, one menubar is set to be displayed. On the top display, it is placed at the top of the display (like macOS). On the bottom display, it is placed at the bottom of the display (like Windows).

[image]

---

**Problem**

When I *snap* a window to resize it to fit the left/right-half part of the display, the title bar (of the window) and the menu bar (of the desktop environment) overlap. Precisely, it seems the window is resized without accounting for the height of the menubar.

Initial state:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Actual result:
[image]

---

**When The Problem Occurs**

As far as I tested, the problem occurs only when

- I use dual display,
- <del>and the menubar is placed at the top of the display like macOS.</del> and the menubar is placed at the boundary (i.e. edge) of the two displays.

---

**Question**

How can I avoid this strange and annoying behavior?

---

**Related Questions**

[KDE]

- [Maximized windows go under vertical taskbar with dual monitors on KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266631/maximized-windows-go-under-vertical-taskbar-with-dual-monitors-on-kde)
- The same bug is also [known on KDE](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=323230) with no solutions for around 7 years.

[Gnome]

- [Gnome panel hides window titlebar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28263/gnome-panel-hides-window-titlebar)

[Xcfe]

- [windows maximize to full screen and bottom hides behind the panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413197/windows-maximize-to-full-screen-and-bottom-hides-behind-the-panel)

Answer (score 0):

On parrot, with mate desktop I experienced the same issue with high dpi screen, I went to mate tweak > windows and turned off and on high dpi. Fixed it for now.

I think the issue is when scaling to high dpi, the offset is the same amount of pixels before and after the scaling.